# Toggle Visual Studio 2013 replace confirmation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I misclicked and unchecked the `show this warning` toggle on the replace all option without realising it until it was too late.

How can I toggle the confirmation to show again?

Comment: What warning exactly? Can you remember anything of the use of the warning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset the "Don't show this dialog again" settings for Visual Studio and ReSharper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323310/how-to-reset-the-dont-show-this-dialog-again-settings-for-visual-studio-and-r)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I mean the confirmation you normally get when you do the 'replace all' option. Unchecking this means you start it directly.

Comment: @Thomas: That has nothing to do with this issue. It's a general VS settings toggle, not Resharper related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in <kbd>Options</kbd> => <kbd>Environment</kbd> => <kbd>Find and Replace</kbd>, just tick `Display warning message`:

[image]