# Visual Studio Extensions - Calling Options Window and Id for Test Menu

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio extension but I'm struggling with a few points.

- When creating a Menu Command, it goes by default to the Tools menu ( id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"). I want to change it to the Test menu, but I can't find the id for it anywhere.
- How can I add a call to the Options window? Basically I want to have a Tools > My Menus > Options that goes straight to my items in the Options windows.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine a menu item id, you can use the `EnableVSIPLogging` registry key described here: [Using EnableVSIPLogging to identify menus and commands with VS 2005 + SP1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dr._ex/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1/).

Note if you use Visual Studio 2017, you will have to do it in VS' private registry, using the procedure described here: [Access Visual Studio 2017's private registry hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916299/access-visual-studio-2017s-private-registry-hive), and the `EnableVSIPLogging` value would be located in a key that will look like this (5e87da33 will be something different, specific to your setup):

```
<your private key name>\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_5e87da33\General
```

Once this is done you can <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> click on "Test" and it will show you this:

[image]

Don't forget to do the reverse.

To show your own option page, create a menu item (using vsct, etc.), and call [Package.ShowOptionPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826083.aspx) when clicked.

Comment: That worked perfectly! May I bother you with another one? The options page: is there a recommended way to store/save the settings? I was planning to store it in a json file, so I could load/read from it every time the options page is opened. But maybe theres an easy/proper way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: @Icaroto - VS provides classes for storing user settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/writing-to-the-user-settings-store

Comment: Hi @Simon, Thanks for the link. So basically this is the recommended way from MS? I mean, I have quite a lot of settings to save so I was concerned that this method wasn't a good idea.