# Can't find Register Entries for Visual Studio Experimental Instance

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx

Every documentation from Visual Studio (2013, 15 17) says the Visual Studio Experimental Instance will have its own register entries in the Registry Editor under xxExp and xxExp_Config Keys.

I can't find those Keys/Folders under HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsot/Visual Studio, but i know they exist as i can create/edit them using WritableSettingsStore.

Can someone tell me where they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio now uses a private registry, which can be found at

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_INSTANCE_IDExp\privateregistry.bin
```

(Replace `INSTANCE_ID` by the VS instance ID)

It can be loaded in `regedit.exe`, but it's not possible to edit the keys from there I think.

Comment: Yes, you can change keys and values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916299/access-visual-studio-2017s-private-registry-hive

Answer (score 0):

You should read through the following topic:

[Changes in Visual Studio 2017 extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/breaking-changes-2017)

In particular the section that talks about the Visual Studio registry.

As Jose mentioned, I've already posted instructions on using regedit to read/edit this privateregistry.bin at:

[Access Visual Studio 2017's private registry hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916299/access-visual-studio-2017s-private-registry-hive)

The above is also documented in the help topic:

[Tools for detecting and managing Visual Studio instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/tools-for-managing-visual-studio-instances#editing-the-registry-for-a-visual-studio-instance)

And an alternative to using regedit, would be to use the new vsregedit.exe utility, which is installed with VS, but I could only find mentioned in the documentation at:

[Controlling notifications in the Visual Studio IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/controlling-updates-to-visual-studio-deployments)

You can learn more about vsregedit.exe, by running it from your developer command prompt with the /? switch.

Sincerely,
Ed Dore
Microsoft Developer Support