# Visual Studio 2017 writing to private registry in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, registry, private

I need to access the private registry from Visual Studio 2017 from a c# program, so the changes there can be used from the running VS instance. To do so I have written an extension that starts a C# method at the startup of Visual Studio. There is a very good idea how to access the private registry here: [Access Visual Studio 2017's private registry hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916299/access-visual-studio-2017s-private-registry-hive)
Unfortunately the method described there using CreateForApplication works only on CurrentUser. I've tried to replace Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey with Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey but I'm getting the keys from the normal Windows registry there:

```
String exeName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
ExternalSettingsManager ext = ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(exeName);
WritableSettingsStore store = ext.GetWritableSettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);

RegistryKey privateRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\", true);
String[] subkeys = privateRegKey.GetSubKeyNames(); 

privateRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\", true);
subkeys = privateRegKey.GetSubKeyNames();
```

I'v also started Visual Studio as administrator.
Can anyone help me and tell me how to modify the private registry for the LocalMachine hive using RegistryKey calls?

Comment: According to the article about the change, "Existing code running inside the Visual Studio process is not impacted. Visual Studio will redirect all registry operations under the HKCU Visual Studio-specific key to the private registry." so there is no HKLM equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you NetMage for pointing me into the right direction. 
I was able to change the registry entries i needed using 
    Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpensSubKey("@Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_Config", true);

It seems actually to be no more need of a LOCAL_MACHINE registry in Visual Studio 2017, so no admin privileges are required to setup Visual Studio components.